# Using classes inside if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I have this kind of code

```
class disable_file_system_redirection:
    if mysystem == "Windows":
        _disable = ctypes.windll.kernel32.Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection
        _revert = ctypes.windll.kernel32.Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection

        def __enter__(self):
            self.old_value = ctypes.c_long()
            self.success = self._disable(ctypes.byref(self.old_value))

        def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
            if self.success:
                self._revert(self.old_value)
    else:
        pass

If test == “yes”:
    with disable_file_system_redirection: 
        try:
            “some code”
else:
    try:
        “same code”
```

As you can see I wrote the same code twice. I cannot merge those two same codes without getting errors. Is there a possible way to do something like that

```
If test = = “yes”:

    with disable_file_system_redirection: 
else: 
    pass #without disable_file_system_redirection:

“some code”
```

Comment: No need of `if-else`, you can opt for `try-except` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can outsource your code into a function:

```
def code_to_do():
   print("code_to_do")

if test == "yes":
    with disable_file_system_redirection:
        try:
            code_to_do()
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
else:
    try:
        code_to_do()
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```